# adding classpath using appassembler-maven-plugin for generating batch file

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, appassembler

I am using appassembler from mojo. What I need to do is I have to add a perticular path of the project (say `%BASEDIR%\resources`) to class path, currently it is adding only `%REPO%` to the classpath. What changes should I do in my pom.xml. I have already provided below code.

```
<configurationDirectory>/some/path</configurationDirectory>
<includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>true</includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>
```

And the output batch file contains

```
set CLASSPATH=%BASEDIR%\\..\SOME\PATH;%REPO%\abc.jar
```

What I my final outcome should be...

```
set CLASSPATH=%BASEDIR%\\..\SOME\PATH;%REPO%\abc.jar;%BASEDIR%\resources
```

What changes should incorporate in my pom.xml for achieving above outcome?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443377/how-can-i-add-classpath-location-by-using-mojo-appassembler-plugin-while-creatin

Comment: yea it is duplicate but no one was responding so created a new thread. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really useful im many cases such as allowing different jdbc drivers or user plugins. In my case I wanted to have a jrebel build and therefore I had to change the classpath and switch the jar by the build directory. But I think it is not very difficult to modify the script to fit your needs. Note that you need maven >= 3.0.3 because since maven 3.0.3 all your plugins are executed in the very same order as they are in your pom.xml. So put this plugin right after your appassembler plugin call.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-beanshell</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <evaluateBeanshell>
              <condition>
                  import java.io.File;
                  import java.nio.file.*;
                  import java.nio.charset.Charset;
                  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

                  print("replace jrebel classpath in ${basedir}/dist/bin/rebelServer");
                  Path path = Paths.get("${basedir}/dist/bin/rebelServer", new String[]{});
                  Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

                  String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);
                  content = content.replaceAll(
                    "\"\\$REPO\"/kic/engine/CoreEngine/[^/]+/CoreEngine\\-[^;:/]+\\.jar", 
                    "${basedir}/build/classes");

                  Files.write(
                    path, 
                    content.getBytes(charset),
                    new OpenOption[]{StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,StandardOpenOption.WRITE}
                  );

                  true;
              </condition>
            </evaluateBeanshell>
          </rules>
          <fail>false</fail>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>  
  </plugin>
```